# JMeter stress testing the TPS can't be improved

Tags: java, testing, jmeter, stress-testing, jmeter-5.0

I am using JMeter to do stress testing to my project.

I set the Constant Throughout Timer as 20/s, and last for 100s. But the actual is: the TPS most get 7/s, and never get 20/s. I don't know why is this.

I want to ask 2 questions:
1、As my understanding,  the JMeter can simulate the stress so it can get TPS at 20/s, is there any config wrong of my JMeter?
2、If for other case, the Jmeter can simulate the stress only depend on the server, is it mean there is problem with my server lead to the TPS can't be improved?

Comment: A Constant Throughput Timer can only slow down tests to reach a target throughput. If your server responds too slowly, or you don't have enough threads to reach your target throughput, you can't reach 20/s. If you haven't already, add a Results Table and check your server response times. If they look ok, add more threads to the ThreadGroup

Comment: Adding more on top of @Simon comments. Check the Response Time of the Request that you are firing, use any of the Listeners to do this, probably check for single User. Once you have that number, increase the Threads so that 20 TPS is reached, if Response Time is 1 second, I know that I will need ~20+ Threads to achieve this, always keep Threads in buffer [use more Threads]. You can also use Throughput Shaping Timer to achieve TPS.

Comment: Thank you Simon, I added more threads, you are right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Constant Throughput Timer](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Constant_Throughput_Timer) can only **pause** the threads in order to **limit** JMeter to the defined number of requests per minute. Moreover, it's more or less precise only on "minute" level, if your test lasts less - you may not see the impact.

Another factor is application response time as JMeter waits for the previous response before sending the next request therefore if the application doesn't respond fast enough you will not be able to reach the desired number of requests per second

And last but not the least is that JMeter should have enough resources in order to send required number of requests per second because if JMeter is not properly configured or the machine where JMeter is running is overloaded - you will not be able to send requests fast enough even the application can handle more load.

So recommendations are:

1. Make sure you provide enough threads (virtual users) to conduct the required load in the [Thread Group](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Thread_Group)
2. Make sure to follow [JMeter Best Practices](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html)
3. Make sure to monitor the baseline health metrics of the machine where JMeter is running (CPU, RAM, Network, Disk, etc.), it can be done using [JMeter PerfMon Plugin](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/PerfMon/). If you detect the lack of resources you will need to find another machine and go for [Distributed Testing](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-to-perform-distributed-testing-in-jmeter/)
4. You can consider [Concurrency Thread Group](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/ConcurrencyThreadGroup/) and [Throughput Shaping Timer](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/ThroughputShapingTimer/#Throughput-Shaping-Timer) combination instead of your current setup, they can be connected via [Feedback Function](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/ConcurrencyThreadGroup/#Use-With-Throughput-Shaping-Timer-Feedback-Function) so JMeter will be able to kick off more threads if current amount is not enough to create the necessary load